Power supply unit only flashes on and off. What does it mean and what should I do?
This PC is from 2014, It's an Asus M51AC-US002S. In 2018 I upgraded the GPU. it's worked fine ever since. I hadn't used it in a few days then 2 days ago I woke it up and the screen just said "HDMI No Connection".
I tried a few things then decided I should just try putting my old GPU in. Well, the current one is stuck. I pushed the latch, it lifted a little, then would not budge any further no matter how I pulled or wiggled it.
Then this afternoon I realized this computer has onboard graphics so I plugged that into my TV to test and it worked! Now I could at least check for updates and check some things. Or at least move important files to my laptop.
So I moved it back to my desk, plugged it into power, monitor, and the ethernet cable. I turned it on and the power supply lit up for a second and went off, then every few seconds it comes on, then back off. No fans or anything. The only other thing that happens is the power button lights up and flashes like the PSU and there's a yellow light on the mobo that stays solid.
My question is, what does the flashing on and off mean? Is the PSU (Power Supply Unit) dead? Is the motherboard fried?

So, what exactly is your question? You should [edit] your question to clarify it.

What exactly is a “PCU”, please clarify your question, by editing your question

What a specific behavior, e.g. a flashing LED - how it flashes, actually indicates varies very much; to be entirely sure you need to find documentation regarding it.
But then that might well be proprietary technical and unreleased information.
My guessing, in this situation:
Might be it cannot provide the power required to drive the GPU, and also detects this fact (PSU broken).
Might also be that the GPU expects (pulls) too much power, i.e. over the capabilities of the PSU (GPU broken).
Apply logic:
Pick out the GPU, try reboot;

PC Works? Yes - suspect broken GPU.
Does not work: Replace PSU.

If the PC works after you've replaced the PSU you have one open question: What is it with the GPU? Will it break the new PSU if you try to run it?

The lights in the PSU (it has a clear case) come on for like half a second, every 5 seconds. I had noticed a yellow light on the mobo but that disappeared when I disconnected the HDMI cable.

So, lookup documentation regarding this.

I came here for help. If I knew there was documentation on it I wouldn't be here.

-> https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/m51ac/helpdesk_manual/

Oh yeah, I looked in the PCs manual and didn't find anything. I believe I'm not using the original power supply anyway.
